# default R personal library location is null

Tags: r

I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 machine to R 3.4.1.  When installing the first non-required package (eg, lubridate), I received the message:

> would you like to create a personal library 'null' to install packages into?

This occurred in both RStudio and the command-line R.  I uninstalled `r-base-core` & reinstalled `r-base` and `r-base-dev` through apt-get, and still had problems.

I noticed that the `/etc/R/` directory contained four fleeting files that existed temporarily during the installation process, but had vanished by the time  `apt-get install r-base r-base-dev` completed.  I reinstalled again to quickly grab and paste those files to the desktop.  After re-installing again, I copied them into `/etc/R/` with:

```
~/Desktop/temp$ sudo cp repositories.dpkg-new /etc/R/repositories
~/Desktop/temp$ sudo cp Rprofile.site.dpkg-new /etc/R/Rprofile.site
~/Desktop/temp$ sudo cp ldpaths.dpkg-new /etc/R/ldpaths
~/Desktop/temp$ sudo cp Makeconf.dpkg-new /etc/R/Makeconf
```

The second step was to uncomment the second like below, found in `/etc/R/Renviron`.  Apparently this is a recent change in the r-base packaging by @dirk-eddelbuettel.

```
# edd Jun 2017  Comment-out R_LIBS_USER
#R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'}
##R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/Library/R/3.4/library'}
```

I have a two-part question:

1. Is the process above recommended, or should I have done something differently? (eg, along the lines of [Setting R_LIBS & avoiding "Would you like to use a personal library instead?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969838).)
2. Are these two steps likely required for future R upgrades on this machine?

Comment: I just uncommented R_LIBS_USER which seemed enough - interested to see what the preferred approach is.

Comment: Comparing ubuntu 17.04 Zesty default package version (3.3) Renviron with Cran (3.4.1).

It looks like a package problem. It may been passed unnoticed because only affect new installs.

I recommend uncommend, and edit to keep the same folder format. : ending with `3.4.1`

`R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4.1'}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. The problem rests in the "commenting out" of those lines, made without checking compatibility. The same problem happens if you try to install a library manually within the REPL, eg using:

```
install.packages("survival")
```

With the difference that you get an "NA" error instead of "null".

Solution for future R upgrades, if you want minimal hassle:

- Restore the /etc/R/Renviron to the package default, so that it won't ask for your input (or just be overwritten) next time R is upgraded
- Add a Renviron in your home directory, eg `$HOME/.Renviron`, with  the following content:

`R_LIBS_USER="${HOME}/R/${R_PLATFORM}-library/3.4.1/"`

Personally, each time R upgrades I reinstall all libraries with the new version. So I will modify that `3.4.1` with `3.4.2` or whatever new version I have, and then reinstall the libraries.

If you don't want to reinstall your libraries, you can try to remove the version subdirectory altogether, eg:

`R_LIBS_USER="${HOME}/R/${R_PLATFORM}-library/`

so that your old libraries will be immediately seen by R.

NB: I couldn't find a way to put the R version inside the Renviron, sadly, but this could be achieved using an .Rprofile instead (since that can contain R code).

Answer (score 3):

On your computer, your current library is named after your R version.

For instance, my current lib is :

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/colin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3"
```

as my current R version is 3.3.

So yes, every time you'll update R, you'll face this lib problem. Note that you can set the path to your old library with `.libPaths(new = "path/to/your/lib")` or copy and paste your old library in the new one.

Colin

Comment: I think I understand the path construction (and that it reflects the version of R).  But I don't believe I have ever needed to change that settings (eg, in the Renviron file) in the ~3 years I've used this computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that for me the most suitable solution was to edit `/etc/R/Renviron.site`:

`# nano /etc/R/Renviron`

And uncomment the line where it sets `R_LIBS_USER` environment variable.

Et voilà!

I can again use `library()`, `require()`, and `install.packages()` within R.