# Installing packages R (Ubuntu)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I have a problem with R, I haven't experienced before. Before writing here I checked the forums but couldn't solved my problem. I saw somebody experiencing this problem.
First, I use Ubuntu 16.04 and R 3.4.1 (Single candle). But I can not install any packages. First it said the directory is not writeable and if I want to create a personal library?

> lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writeable Would you like 
>   to use a personal library instead?  (y/n)

I couldn't :( I checked forums another option was changing permission, i coded:
1. `cd /usr/local/lib/R`
2. `sudo chmod o+w site-library`
3. `ls -l` but it didn't work.

When I want to download a package, it installs it at /tmp folder. And i can not use it, cause when i want to open it with "library()" it says there is no package like that. I copied the package from the /tmp folder and pasted it to the folder other packages are (i didn't installed them by myself, they were there) but still it doesn't recognize the package. 
I didn't experienced this with my windows pc, and a friend with Ubuntu said he is usind R and Rstudio without problem. So what is wrong with mine :( ???

Comment: Is it similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873972

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default R personal library location is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873972/default-r-personal-library-location-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `r` or `rstudio` doesn't have permission to write inside theses directories.

You should change your `R_LIBS` for a local directory, take a look in `/etc/R/Renviron.site` and uncomment the `R_LIBS` line or define it if needed.

Check if a R folder exists in your home like this  `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4`, it should be your `R_LIBS` address. If it doesn't exist you can create one like `~/R/library/` and define the same in `Renviron.site`.

More information, check [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) or `help(Startup)`.