# Library path in Renviron file commented out when R upgraded

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently upgraded R from 3.4 to 3.4.1 and this caused a problem with accessing installed packages. After some searching I am able to fix this by setting up a `.Renviron` file in my home directory and setting `R_LIBS` path.

I subsequently realized that an `.Renviron` already exits under `etc/R`, but when I looked through it I noticed the following:

```
# edd Jun 2017  Comment-out R_LIBS_USER
#R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'}
##R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/Library/R/3.4/library'}
```

So it appears that those couple of lines were commented out when I upgraded R (note the date). My questions is why were they commented out?

Comment: See the advice I received here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873972/default-r-personal-library-location-is-null

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is a duplicate question and I should delete it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default R personal library location is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873972/default-r-personal-library-location-is-null)

Comment: Only issue I say, I don't believe your actual question was answered!

Comment: I think the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44886783/1082435) by @Fabio addressed by by concerns, but I concede I won't know for sure until a few upgrade cycles have succeeded.  But it appears that approach will not require any config changes after updated through apt-get.  The comment by gustavo-garcia addressed my curiosity about why it might have happened.